# CNTK: cloning a single layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

My current goal is to clone a single layer from an already trained model.

The first problem is that the `clone()` method clones the entire graph from the supplied node which is not what I want.

So I tried cloning it manually (in this case a Dense layer) by retrieving its weights from the node as follows:

```
node = C.logging.graph.find_by_name(model, 'node')
C.layers.Dense(node.shape, init=node.W.value, init_bias=node.b.value)
```

Unfortunately this does not work since I get the following shady error:

```
TypeError: in method 'random_initializer_with_rank', argument 1 of type 'CNTK::ParameterInitializer const &'
```

Comment: `C.layers.Dense(node.shape, init=node.W.value, init_bias=node.W.value)` is probably not correct, since you are trying to initialize both weights and biases with `node.W.value` but I tried it with a small example myself and got the same error, which is odd since the python API docs state that init and init_bias should handle np arrays

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. I correctly used `node.b.value` and got that error.

Comment: Yeah, I also created a MWE and recreated the exact error message. Interestingly though I was able to do the same with convolutional layers and it worked correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clone()` method does not necessarily clone the entire graph. It allows you to "cut out" a piece of graph, via the `substitutions` argument. The `substitutions` argument specifies the input nodes of the part of the graph you want to clone; basically where you want to cut it.

For example, to clone a middle layer of a stack, identify

- its root, let's call it `layer_root`
- its input(s). Let's say there is one input node, you store it as `layer_input`

Then you should be able to clone just this part according to this following code sketch:

```
substitutions = {
    layer_input : C.placeholder(name='cloned_layer_input')
}
cloned_layer = layer_root.clone(clone_method, substitutions)
```

The `substitutions` will cause `clone()` to stop cloning once it hits `layer_input`, and in the clone, replace it with the placeholder.

The result will be a callable, like any layers of the layers lib (like `C.Dense()`) or any function defined with `@C.Function`, which is I believe what you are looking for.